# How to use nvcc as compiler in ns3

Tags: c++, compilation, nvcc, ns-3

I'm trying to use cuda in ns3, but when I tried to run `CXX="nvcc" ./waf configure`, it shows the following message on the screen:

```
Checking for 'g++' (C++ compiler)        : not found 
Checking for 'clang++' (C++ compiler)    : not found 
Checking for 'icpc' (C++ compiler)       : not found 
could not configure a C++ compiler!
(complete log in /home/kelu/workspace/ns-3.24/build/config.log)
```

I checked the config.log, it says the following:

```
Checking for 'g++' (C++ compiler)
find program='nvcc' paths=['/usr/local/sbin', '/usr/local/bin', '/usr/sbin', '/usr/bin', '/sbin', '/bin', '/usr/local/cuda/bin'] var='CXX' -> ['nvcc']
from /home/kelu/workspace/ns-3.24: Could not determine the compiler type
not found
----------------------------------------
Checking for 'clang++' (C++ compiler)
find program='nvcc' paths=['/usr/local/sbin', '/usr/local/bin', '/usr/sbin', '/usr/bin', '/sbin', '/bin', '/usr/local/cuda/bin'] var='CXX' -> ['nvcc']
from /home/kelu/workspace/ns-3.24: Not clang/clang++
not found
----------------------------------------
Checking for 'icpc' (C++ compiler)
find program='nvcc' paths=['/usr/local/sbin', '/usr/local/bin', '/usr/sbin', '/usr/bin', '/sbin', '/bin', '/usr/local/cuda/bin'] var='CXX' -> ['nvcc']
from /home/kelu/workspace/ns-3.24: Not icc/icpc
not found
from /home/kelu/workspace/ns-3.24: could not configure a C++ compiler!
```

nvcc is located in /usr/local/cuda/bin, which is in path. But it seems to me that the building script of ns3 does not resolve nvcc as a compiler.

Could anybody please tell me the right way to make nvcc the CXX compiler in ns3?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found a way to use nvcc in ns-3, but I did find a work around for this problem. I'm happy to share my solution here to help others:

1. Make your cuda code a static library:
   `ar rcs libcudacode.a a.o b.o c.o` (you need to make the *.o files first using g++, nvcc, or anything else you want)
2. put libcudacode.a in `/your/lib/folder/` and put your cuda code in `/your/src/folder`
3. Add lib folder and src folder into waf: 
   `CXXFLAGS_EXTRA="-I/your/src/folder -I/your/cuda/dir/include" LINKFLAGS_EXTRA="-L/your/lib/folder -L/your/cuda/dir/lib64 -lcudacode -lcudart" ./waf configure`.
4. `./waf`

Your code should be compiled now. You can access any public functions in your cuda code by `#including "corresponding_header.h"`

A little bit explanation:

1. `CXXFLAGS_EXTRA` and `LINKFLAGS_EXTRA` add compilation flags in ns-3's compiling system. You need to add both your cuda code and NVidia's cuda library to use the functions.
2. If you used any other libraries, also put them in `CXXFLAGS_EXTRA` and `LINKFLAGS_EXTRA`
3. Check the cuda directory name in your system. It's probably not lib64 in your machine.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem probably was that Waf actually checks the compiler's built-in #defines to check whether a compiler invoked as "gcc" actually is gcc or not. As a concrete example, it will error out if it detects that the compiler is Intel's icc (because it #defined __INTEL_COMPILER) but was invoked with a "gcc" command line!

The code that does the identification is at https://waf.io/apidocs/_modules/waflib/Tools/c_config.html#get_cc_version .

So, if you don't have a compiler which tries **hard** to look like one of the supported ones, looks like you are supposed to write your own Waf tool.

However, you can try to hack your way through. For example, let's say that your compiler is compatible enough with gcc but still it doesn't get past Waf's absurdly stringent test. A fix is to run "waf configure" using the real gcc, and then edit the file where Waf stores the detection results, so at the build step Waf will actually run your compiler instead of gcc. You can do this by editing build/c4che/_cache.py: change the CC definition to your compiler's full path.